# What makes a definition subject to monomorphism restriction?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, type-inference, monomorphism-restriction

Why is this definition affected by the monomorphism restriction?

```
z = \n -> n  + 1
```

and this isn't:

```
z n = n + 1
```

Comment: you can find the answer in the canonical duplicate, under **"When does it happen?"**. Specifically, it says "When a pattern binding consists of only a variable name it's called a simple pattern binding.. **The monomorphism restriction applies to simple pattern bindings!**". As defined by the Haskell Report, referenced in that answer as well.

Comment: @WillNess Let's continue in the chat. How to provide a it?

Comment: @WillNess anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @WillNess This sentence *The monomorphism restriction applies to simple pattern bindings!* makes it clear.